# python csv reader - convert string to int on the for line when iterating

Tags: python

I'm interested in not having to write map the int function to the tuple of strings where I currently have it.  See the last part of my example:

```
import os
import csv

filepath =  os.path.normpath("c:/temp/test.csv")

individualFile = open(filepath,'rb')
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(individualFile.read(1000))

individualFile.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(individualFile,dialect)

names = reader.next()

print names

def buildTree(arityList):
    if arityList == []:
        return 0            
    else:
        tree = {}
        for i in xrange(arityList[0][0],arityList[0][1]+1):
            tree[i] = buildTree(arityList[1:])
        return tree


census = buildTree([(1,12),(1,6),(1,4),(1,2),(0,85),(0,14)])

for m, f, s, g, a, c, t in reader:
    try:
        m,f,s,g,a,c,t = map(int,(m,f,s,g,a,c,t))
        census[m][f][s][g][a][c] += t
    except:
        print "error"
        print m, f, s, g, a, c, t
        break
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
for m, f, s, g, a, c, t in map(int,reader):
    try:
        census[m][f][s][g][a][c] += t
    except:
        print "error"
        print m, f, s, g, a, c, t
        break
```

I try this and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

I'm having trouble understand this error message.  I thought reader was an iterable object - not a list.  It returns a list for each iteration, but it itself is not a list, correct?  I guess that is more of a side question. What I really want to know is if there is a way to do what I am trying to do.  Sorry for the code that doesn't really relate, but I thought I would include my whole example.  Feel free to tear it to bits! :)  I'm wondering if it might be better to just have one dict where the key is a tuple instead of this nested dictionary stuff, but even so, I'm still interested in figuring out my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you want is something like:

```
def int_wrapper(reader):
    for v in reader:
        yield map(int, v)
```

Your code would then look like:

```
reader = csv.reader(individualFile,dialect)
reader = int_wrapper(reader)

# all that other stuff

for m, f, s, g, a, c, t in reader:
    try:
        census[m][f][s][g][a][c] += t
    except:
        print "error"
        print m, f, s, g, a, c, t
        break
```

This is just using a generator function to wrap the reader and convert the input to integers.

The origin of the `TypeError` is that `reader` is a generator function which `yield`s lists of values. When you apply `map` to it, you are applying `map` to a 'list' of lists. This is different than applying `map` to a list of values which you do when you write it out the long way.

For illustration, another way to do it is

```
for m, f, s, g, a, c, t in (map(int, v) for v in reader):
    # code
```

This just uses an *in situ* generator expression instead of defining a function. It's a matter of taste.

Comment: this is awesome.  i was just reading about generators and this helps me understand them better already!  sorry to act like a total noob/fanboy, but i am just starting to get into python, and it is so damn awesome.

Comment: @oob. Don't sweat it. I can use all the fans I can get. Oh wait....you were talking about python. Yeah, pythons pretty cool too.