# Why does this generator return a single list while another one using map retains the list-of-lists format?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I want to read some csv files containing row vectors with python. The row vectors are of differing length, so some fields are empty and contain an empty string. Converting such a list of lists to a numpy array results in an array of strings, and during my fiddling to convert the array to float (based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682321/python-csv-reader-convert-string-to-int-on-the-for-line-when-iterating)) I came up with two solutions that seemed identical to me, but which obviously aren't. Maybe someone could put the difference into words.

**Solution 1:**

```
def float_wrapper(reader):
    for row in reader:
        for val in row:
            if (type(val) == str) and (len(val) == 0):   
                val = 0.0
            yield float(val)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
def str2float2(val):
    if type(val) == str: 
        if len(val) == 0:   
            val = 0.0
    return float(val)

def float_wrapper(reader):
    for row in reader:
        yield map(str2float2, row)
```

**Common code:**

```
A = []
with open('parameters.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    reader = float_wrapper(reader)
    for row in reader:
        A.append(row)
```

With solution 1, A is single list of floats, while using solution 2 it is a list of lists in the original format. Why is this? Which other alternatives might I be missing?

Comment: Because `map` returns a `list` & `float` returns a `float` (NOT a container)

Comment: I'd appreciate a more detailed explanation of what exactly is happening and what is being iterated behind the scenes, actually.

Comment: thefourtheye did what I was going to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` function can only be applied to an iterable and for each element in the iterable it applies the function and the stores the corresponding result in a list and returns it. That's why you are getting a list in the second generator.

In the first solution, you are taking each and every line and then each and every value and processing it and then you are returning the last value of it in each iteration. So, In the common code, when you run the `for` loop with `reader`, you will be getting a single element for each and every line.

In the second solution, you are taking each and every line and the using `map` you are applying the `float` for all the values and generating a list. So, In the common code, when you run the `for` loop with `reader`, you will be getting a list of elements for each and every line processed.

Comment: I had an indentation error in the original post that changes your second paragraph, but I guess what helped me understand was that the common code iterates over each mention of "yield" in the generator. Cheers.